# SQL multiple tables with

Tags: sql, unique-constraint

I have a SQL database with 2 tables:

**Client**

```
ClientID
ClientName
ClientBirthdate
```

**Address**

```
ClientID
Addressline1
Addressline2
Telephone1
Telephone2
```

It is possible for a client to have multiple addresses, so ClientID is not a unique value in the Address-table. My problem is that I want to send a textmessage to every *unique* phonenumber. Telephone1 and Telephone2 can both be empty, so basically I have no idea how many unique phonenumbers a client has. When I join them now, it looks something like this:

```
ClientID  | ClientName | Telephone1 | Telephone2
------------------------------------------------
Client001 | James      | 12345      | 22312
Client001 | James      | 12345      | 
Client002 | Alfred     |            | 11111
Client002 | Alfred     | 11111      | 
Client002 | Alfred     | 22222      |
```

While what I want is something like this:

```
ClientID  | ClientName | Number1    | Number2
----------------------------------------------
Client001 | James      | 12345      | 22312
Client001 | Alfred     | 11111      | 22222
```

Currently I have no idea how to achieve this. Can anyone shine their light on the issue?

Thanks on beforehand,

James.

EDIT: The database already exists, and is already filled. I can't change the structure of the database, I can only do SELECT-queries.

Comment: What happens if a client has 3 phone number?

Comment: Yes, you can create your primary key for the Address table from the combined columns ClientID and Addressline1. If you are going to allow multiple telephone numbers then you might consider adding a third table to hold the telephone numbers. Your third table would have two columns ClientID and Telephone.

Comment: Then I want it as well. That is exactly my problem. I want all the unique phonenumbers, but I don't know how many they can be.

Comment: @JohnSheridan, I sadly have no influence over the structure of the database, it is already made and filled, I am writing a query for it.

Comment: Using "Number#" as a column name limits total numbers of values. I think Gidil also pointed out that.

Comment: I know, I was just making something up for the titles of those columns. It really doesn't matter. I just want all the numbers. And mostly, I want one line per ClientID.

Comment: If you need to have one row per client, I think the only way to go is dynamic SQL. Are you sure you want to go there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my suggested solution (if I understood the problem correctly):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CLIENTID, 
                CLIENTNAME, 
                TELEPHONE 
FROM   (SELECT T1.CLIENTID, 
               T1.CLIENTNAME, 
               T2.TELEPHONE1 AS Telephone 
        FROM   CLIENT T1 
               INNER JOIN (SELECT CLIENTID, 
                                  TELEPHONE1 
                           FROM   ADDRESS 
                           WHERE  TELEPHONE1 IS NOT NULL)T2 
                       ON T1.CLIENTID = T2.CLIENTID 
        UNION 
        SELECT T1.CLIENTID, 
               T1.CLIENTNAME, 
               T2.TELEPHONE2 AS Telephone 
        FROM   CLIENT T1 
               INNER JOIN (SELECT CLIENTID, 
                                  TELEPHONE2 
                           FROM   ADDRESS 
                           WHERE  TELEPHONE2 IS NOT NULL)T2 
                       ON T1.CLIENTID = T2.CLIENTID)T
```

You can find a full example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0f4d8/7).
Please let me know if you have any more question on this.

Comment: Of course. I was trying to get every client on one line, but it's far easier to do it like this, so then you have one unique phonenumber per line. Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
select distinct ClientID, ClientName, Number1  
  from ...  
union
select distinct ClientID, ClientName, Number2
  from ...  
  where Number2 is not null
```

Comment: I was trying to vote this up as useful, but it seems that I can't since I don't have 15 reputation yet, even though it is my own question. Whenever I do, I'll come back for it, thanks for helping out!